# Typescript interface A extends B, but is missing properties from B?

Tags: typescript, interface, extension-methods

I don't understand how TypeScript interfaces work, apparently.
I have this:

```
import type { Socket, Handshake } from 'socket.io';
import type { Session } from './session';

export interface SessionHandshake extends Handshake {
  session: Session;
}

export interface SessionSocket extends Socket {
  handshake: SessionHandshake;
  id: string;
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is extending the given "Socket" interface from socket.io, by adding an "id" property and extending the "handshake" property.
The latter is not accepted by TypeScript.
TS claims that "SessionHandshake is missing x, y, z properties from type Handshake".
But how can this be? I defined SessionHandshake as an extension of the Handshake interface. How can TS claim it does not have all of Handshake's properties?

Using TS 4.1.3 here.

Comment: How are you using these types? What code is throwing the _"SessionHandshake is missing x, y, z properties from type Handshake"_ error?

Comment: It's a compile error.
The `export interface SessionSocket` is where it tells me there is a problem:
"Interface 'SessionSocket' incorrectly extends interface 'Socket'. Types of property 'handshake' are incompatible. Type 'SessionHandshake' is missing the following properties from type 'Handshake': headers, time, address, xdomain and 5 more.`

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `extends` can be used for interfaces and classes only.

`Handshake` is a type, therefore you cannot use the keyword `extends`

If you just want to declare a type that has additional properties, you can use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types):

```js
export type SessionHandshake = Handshake & { session: string };
```

Comment: I unaccepted the answer now, even though it first made some sense to me (although not explaining why).
Guys in the Typescript Discord told me it's no problem to exend types. (And indeed, that is not what my compiler is complaining about. Just the extension does not bring the expected result for me: deletes properties of the original type that was exended.)
They said the underlying problem seems to be that the type I'm extending from is a class. (even though, again, the compiler does not complain about the extension, it just does not result in what I expect: deleting properties.)

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: It still does not really make sense to me though, lol. I still don't get it why it is like that.

Comment: The answerer is correct in that you can't extend types, but that isn't what you were doing here to start with, you were extending the interface **with** a type, which is fine. Just for any future Googler who is confused by this.